# Copiar table de HTML a tabla en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Buenas colegas: Necesito pasar la información de un table en HTML a una tabla en mi base de datos MySQL..

El botón de HTML se llama name="btnCopiar" invoca la función.

Este es el código que tengo en el HTML con una función de AJAX

```js
<script>
    $("btnCopiar").click(function(){
$('#milista tr').each(function() {
    var nombre= $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
    var usuario = $(this).find('td').eq(1).html();
    var correo = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
 
    $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: "POST",
     url: "RegistrarA.php",
        data: "&nombre="+nombre+"&usuario="+usuario+"&correo="+correo,
     data: {valores:valores},
     success: function(data) { if(data!="");}
    });
   });
});
</script>
```

```js
<script>
    $("btnCopiar").click(function(){
$('#milista tr').each(function() {
    var nombre= $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
    var usuario = $(this).find('td').eq(1).html();
    var correo = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
 
    $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: "POST",
     url: "RegistrarA.php",
        data: "&nombre="+nombre+"&usuario="+usuario+"&correo="+correo,
     data: {valores:valores},
     success: function(data) { if(data!="");}
    });
   });
});
</script>
```

Y este es el código en PHP para el respectivo Registro.

```js
<?php
   
 require ("conexion.php");

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `T_Profesores` (`Tc_Nombre_docente`, `Tc_usuario`, `Tc_correo`, VALUES ('$nombre', '$usuario','$correo')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.assign("RegistroAsistencia.php");
  alert("Gracias!");
  </script>';
    } else {
            // header('Location: ../loans.php?registrationstatus=false');
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.assign("RegistroAsistencia.php");
  alert("No efectuado");
  </script>';
    }

?>
```

Al ejecutarse no realiza una acción, sólo se queda ahí y no escribe en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que estás obteniendo? Mira [ask], recuerda que incluir cualquier detalle puede ser de utilidad por lo que omitirlos puede limitar la ayuda que otros usuarios puedan proporcionarte.

Comment: Aparece este mensaje al debuggear ReferenceError: CopiarTabla is not defined

Comment: Puedes colocar tu HTML, o al menos el botón, sospecho que puede ser la forma en la que invocas a la función desde el botón, pero quiero estar seguro de ello. Solo para corroborar el dato, ¿ese error lo obtienes al hacer clic sobre el botón?

Comment: Le hice un pequeño cambio, para que la acción se realice desde arriba. Aún así algo pasa que no invoca al PHP

Comment: <script>
    $("btnCopiar").click(function(){
$('#milista').each(function() {
    var nombre= $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
    var usuario = $(this).find('td').eq(1).html();
    var correo = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
 
    $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: "POST",
     url: "RegistrarA.php",
        data: "&nombre="+nombre+"&usuario="+usuario+"&correo="+correo,
     data: {valores:valores},
     success: function(data) { if(data!="");}
    });
   });
}
</script>

Comment: Colócalo en tu pregunta para que sea más legible. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar información adicional en cualquier momento. Unifica la info, porque en el comentario me muestras un código que es algo diferente al que se encuentra en tu pregunta.

Comment: Listo, le hice el cambio, muchas gracias,

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://ctporosi.mavisolucionescr.com/Feria/lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE